# sass-brunch omits modified SCSS on live-reload

Tags: phoenix-framework, brunch, sass-brunch

On my Phoenix project, I found a peculiar behavior of `sass-brunch`.

Here are the short descriptions of my problem:

- It generates a correct `app.css` on the `priv/static/css` directory when the Phoenix server started in dev envrionment.
- When I modify one of SCSS files, the `app.css` gets generated but lacks only the lines from the modified SCSS file. It keeps the lines from the unmodified files.
- This problem occurs on Ubuntu 16.04, but not on macOS.

On the log file, I noticed an entry that may be related to this issue:

`[debug] Duplicate channel join for topic "phoenix:live_reload" in Phoenix.LiveReloader.Socket. Closing existing channel for new join.`

I don't see such a line on my Mac.

My environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop
- Phoenix 1.2.5
- Node.js 8.9.1
- npm 5.5.1
- Brunch 2.10.7
- sass-brunch 2.10.4

My `package.json`:

`{
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "brunch build --production",
    "watch": "brunch watch --stdin"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:deps/phoenix_html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "6.0.6",
    "brunch": "2.10.7",
    "clean-css-brunch": "2.10.0",
    "sass-brunch": "^2.10.4",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "2.1.1"
  }
}`

[UPDATE]

I found an interesting fact.

- When I edit SCSS files using vim, the `app.css` gets generated normally.
- When I edit them using *atom*, things do not go well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to my problem.

Put these lines to the `brunch-config.js`:

`watcher: {
    usePolling: true
  }`

As the [documentation](http://brunch.io/docs/config#-watcher-) of Brunch says, watcher gets slower but can be more reliable by setting `true` to this option.

The `usePolling` option is passed to [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar), whose document says:

> `usePolling` (default: `false`). Whether to use fs.watchFile (backed by polling), or fs.watch. If polling leads to high CPU utilization, consider setting this to `false`. It is typically necessary to set this to `true` to successfully watch files over a network, and it may be necessary to successfully watch files in other non-standard situations.

Comment: This did not work for me. Still, any edited sass files do not livereload. I have to stop the server and restart again. Is there any other config that might be missing from the typical brunch config other than this?

Comment: @steventnorris Could you show me your brunch-config.js?

Comment: I was actually able to determine it to be a bug in 2.10.7. 2.10.5 works fine. There has been a PR at this point for the fix merged into master head, but no new version as of yet.